# Azure DevOps - Pre-approve deployment stages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a yaml deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps. The sequence of stages looks like this:

[image: deployment stages]

After the build, dev gets deployed automatically but QA has an approval set. The problem is, I have to wait for build and dev to finish before I can approve QA. Is there a way to approve a stage in advance when starting the build or during it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to approve a stage in advance when starting the build or during it?

Azure devops does not support this feature to approve a stage in advance when starting the build at this moment.

According the document [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass):

> A pipeline is made up of stages. A pipeline author can control whether
>   a stage should run by defining conditions on the stage. Another way to
>   control if and when a stage should run is through approvals and
>   checks.
>
> A stage can consist of many jobs, and each job can consume several
>   resources. Before the execution of a stage can begin, all checks on
>   all the resources used in that stage must be satisfied. Azure
>   Pipelines pauses the execution of a pipeline prior to each stage, and
>   waits for all pending checks to be completed. If any of the checks
>   fails (for example, if you reject an approval on one of the
>   resources), then that stage is not executed.

We could to know that the approvals and checks are set for the **stage** not the pipeline. When our stage has not been started, it will not detect the approvals and checks we set.

But personally think that your request is reasonable, we need to strip the approvals and checks to a certain extent to allow it to be detected when the pipeline starts. You could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have suggested the feature: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1041532/pre-approve-deployment-stages-when-starting-pipeli.html